# Are there any ways to hide the System bar (or Navigation bar) **permanently** on Android?

Tags: android

Are there any ways to hide the System bar (or Navigation bar) **permanently** on Android?
It will re-appear when user touch on screen.

My solution was: catch the event (e.g. Touching) when user interact with screen. But I can only catch it at the second time. The first time I can not. If I can catch at the first time, I think I can force the System bar will be visibility again. 
Have you got any ways to catch the event in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is here is the [code](https://github.com/ppareit/HideBar) Pieter Pareit.